# How do you deal with PGP + Drafts in Thunderbird?

Tags: email, encryption, pgp

I'm having trouble trying to setup a secure email client.

I have marked an option to always encrypt emails by default. But they only get encrypted right before being sent, so sometimes a draft is saved in plain text and uploaded to the server.

What can I do about that?

Comment: I'm using Enigmail 1.4.3, and if the message has encryption enabled, Enigmail always asks me if I want to encrypt the message before saving.

Comment: also, in Enigmail there's a setting under "Copies & Folders" where you can select to keep your drafts in a local folder. not sure whether it's the default or not though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes Thunderbird asks whether you want to encrypt the draft before being saved.

It would be nice if that option was somewhere in Preferences or something to set it up from day 1, or be able to change it if you made a mistake when Thunderbird asked the question.